# FlowDocument/RichTextBox with Hyperlinks using MVVM

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, mvvm

I am developing some specialized log viewer in which I display a list of log entries in a list view.

The application consists of a Window (actually, using [Catel](http://catel.codeplex.com/), so it's a DataWindow) and in it I have the UI. Since I am using MVVM I also created corresponding VM. My Model is the Log that have a collection of LogEntrys. The Log is loaded in the VM upon user interaction.

Each LogEntry has a Message property which is some text (string property) that I want to parse into XAML and transform parts of it to hyperlinks. When the user clicks the hyperlink I want to perform some command that is defined in the main VM (must be there as it uses some properties that belongs in the VM).

Initially I tried to use RichTextBox. Since the WPF one does not support binding I decided to use the RTB from Extended WPF Toolbox ([here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RichTextBox&referringTitle=Home)).

I created a custom `ITextFormatter` that reads the text and builds a `FlowDocument` (note that in the `ITextFormatter` the `FlowDocument` (document parameter) is passed in). In `SetText`:

```
foreach (var line in text.Split('\n'))
{
    //some manipulations
    Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
    para.Inlines.Add(new Run(manipulatedText1));
    para.Inlines.Add(CreateHyperLink(manipulatedText2));
    document.Blocks.Add(para);
}
```

The `CreateHyperLink` function should build the `Hyperlink` and set it's command and parameters:

```
private Hyperlink CreateHyperlink(string text)
{
    var hLink = new Hyperlink(new Bold(new Run(text)));
    hLink.TargetName = text;
    //Attach a command and set arguments (target etc)
    hLink.Command = ???
    hLink.TargetName = text;
    //Do some formatting
    return hLink;
}
```

This got me to a stage that I am seeing my formatted content in the RTB in the `ListView` but they are only underlined, behave as regular text and have no action. (Posted question [here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/354338) but no answer yet).

Then, when trying to find a solution I stumbled upon the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`. I created an `IValueConverter` that parse the text (message) and build the document with the hyperlink. This seems like a slightly simpler and cleaner solution. Using this approach I got the formatted message display and the Hyperlinks are recognized as such (appear in blue and as a "whole" unit) but still no luck in getting the command to fire.

Thus I have two questions:

1. Which control is better choice or what are the pros and cons of using each one? `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` is inherently read only and may support better formatting (?) but it does give some problems with scrolling the `ListView` with the mouse (when over a `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`, it does not scroll the list, maybe can be fixed)
2. How do I go about passing a command from VM to the hyperlink an having it execute? I assume some binding should be done but not sure how/where. I tried to create in both `ITextFormatter` and `IValueConverter` an `ICommand` `DependancyProperty` and use its value when rendering the FlowDocument but either it is not legal (as the instance is created as static resource) or I am not binding it correctly

I tried (in ):

```
<local:TextToFlowDocumentConverter 
         x:Key="textToFlowDocumentConverter" 
         HyperlinkCommand="{Binding NavigateDnHyperlinkCommand, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
         AncestorType={x:Type catel:DataWindow}}, Path=DataContext}"/>
```

I guess I can instantiate the formatter/converter on the VM but that's not proper MVVM...

BTW, I also tried to "hard code" the link when parsing (`CreateHyperLink` above)

```
hLink.RequestNavigate += new System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventHandler(hLink_RequestNavigate);
```

and this did not work for both controls

I addition, I set in XAML the `Hyperlink.Click` and `Hyperlink.RequestNavigate` (attached properties(?)) and have them in the Window's code behind - and this does work (NOTE: in case of RTB you have to set `IsDocumentEnabled="True"` and `IsReadOnly="True"`!)

Thanks,

Tomer

Comment: I think a possible direction would be an attached property... working on it - updates later. If it's not a good idea - I'd be happy to know

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote above, I tried to do this with an attached behavior. Unfortunately, I was not able to get it working but I think it is some nuances I am missing and maybe someone can come up with it - and also, maybe this answer can be useful.

So, what I tried to do is create a new class with an `AttachedProperty` that can be used to update the `FlowDocument`'s Hyperlink.Command:

```
/// <summary>
/// RichTextBox helper class to allow bind command to hyperlinks in RichTextBox.Document
/// </summary>
public class RichTextBoxHyperlinkHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the Command associated with DependencyObject
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The DependencyObject</param>
    /// <returns>ICommand associated with this DependencyObject</returns>
    public static ICommand GetHyperlinkCommand(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(HyperlinkCommandProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the ICommand associated with this DependencyObject (RichTextBox)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The DependencyObject (RichTextBox)</param>
    /// <param name="value">The new ICommand value</param>
    public static void SetHyperlinkCommand(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HyperlinkCommandProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HyperlinkCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HyperlinkCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HyperlinkCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(RichTextBoxHyperlinkHelper),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((RichTextBox)null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnHyperlinkCommandSet)));

    /// <summary>
    /// A method to run when command is set initialy
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private static void OnHyperlinkCommandSet(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rtb = d as RichTextBox;

        if (rtb == null)
        {
            //TODO: Throw?
            return;
        }

        FixHyperLinks(rtb);
    }

    private static void FixHyperLinks(RichTextBox rtb)
    {
        //Get the command attached to this RichTextBox
        var command = GetHyperlinkCommand(rtb);

        if (command != null && rtb.Document != null)
        {
            //Add event handler for data context changed - in which case the .Document may change as well
            rtb.DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(rtb_DataContextChanged);

            //Traverse the document, find hyperlinks and set their command
            Queue<Block> blocks = new Queue<Block>();   //Use queue instead of recursion...
            rtb.Document.Blocks.ToList().ForEach(b => blocks.Enqueue(b));   //Add top level blocks

            while (blocks.Count > 0)    //While still blocks to process
            {
                var currentBlock = blocks.Dequeue();    //Get block

                //If paragraph - check inlines for Hyperlinks
                if (currentBlock is Paragraph)
                {
                    foreach (var item in (currentBlock as Paragraph).Inlines)
                    {
                        //If an Hyperlink - set its command
                        if (item is Hyperlink)
                        {
                            (item as Hyperlink).Command = command;
                        }
                        //TODO: process child inlines etc
                    }                       
                }

                //TODO: Process other types of blocks/child blocks
            }

            //Make sure document is enabled and read only so Hyperlinks work
            rtb.IsDocumentEnabled = true;
            rtb.IsReadOnly = true;
        }
    }

    //On case of data context change - rehook the command (calling FixHyperLinks)
    static void rtb_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rtb = sender as RichTextBox;

        if (rtb != null)
            FixHyperLinks(rtb);
    }
}
```

Then, supposedly, it is used like so:

```
<ext:RichTextBox Text="{Binding Message}" IsDocumentEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True"
                 local:RichTextBoxHyperlinkHelper.HyperlinkCommand="{Binding RelativeSource=
                 {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}},
                 Path=DataContext.NavigateDnHyperlinkCommand, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
    <ext:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
        <local:TextDnRtfFormatter />
    </ext:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
    <ext:RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
        </Style>                                    
    </ext:RichTextBox.Resources>
</ext:RichTextBox>
```

When stepping through the code I do see that the hyperlink's Command is being set properly to the command bound from the VM but when clicking the Hyperlink nothing happens.

It is worth nothing that if I set the command inside `TextDnRtfFormatter` to a command that is defined internally it does fire the old command even though it was supposedly replaced by the command from the VM that is set in the `RichTextBoxHyperlinkHelper`.

In addition, I also try to use behavior to solve this (`EventToCommand`) and eventually I've solved it in a none-so-MVVM way by sending a message from `TextDnRtfFormatter` and catching it in the VM (by using Catel `IMessageMediator`)